# How to identify on command line VR videos? .. And batch delete them

Tags: command-line, scripts, video, ffmpeg

Sometimes I accidentaly download VR (Virtual reality) videos. I can't view VR videos on my Linux box (even on macOS its not working).

How to identify VR videos (`mediainfo` or similar tool) and delete them in a folder like `/torrents/complete`?

Here example video meta data:

```
$ mediainfo example.mp4
General
Complete name                            : example.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 83.1 MiB
Duration                                 : 9 min 40 s
Overall bit rate                         : 1 201 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.0.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 9 min 40 s
Bit rate                                 : 1 067 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 440 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.000
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.041
Stream size                              : 73.8 MiB (89%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 152 r19 ba24899
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=1 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x3 / me=dia / subme=1 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=12 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=1 / keyint=125 / keyint_min=12 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=crf / mbtree=0 / crf=26.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / pb_ratio=1.30 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 9 min 40 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : C L R Ls Rs LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 8.86 MiB (11%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

Thanks:

I used

```
find . -type f -name '[^.]*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ratio=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=display_aspect_ratio -of csv=p=0 "$1"); if [[ "$ratio" == 2:1 ]]; then echo "$1"; fi' _ {} \;
```

It seems `rtorrent` created dot files.

I only go one false positive output:

```
mediainfo xxx.mp4
General
Complete name                            : xxx.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 613 MiB
Duration                                 : 27 min 38 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 3 099 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-06-12 05:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-06-12 05:00:00
Writing application                      : Lavf53.6.0

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 27 min 38 s
Bit rate                                 : 3 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 320 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.000
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.610
Stream size                              : 590 MiB (96%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 116
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=24 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=3000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-06-12 05:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-06-12 05:00:00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 27 min 38 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 107 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 21.1 MiB (3%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2013-06-12 05:00:00
Tagged date                              : UTC 2013-06-12 05:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no foolproof way based on the info you provided because there is nothing listed that is unique to a VR video.

However, perhaps you can assume that any video with a 2:1 Display Aspect Ratio is probably VR:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/torrents/complete" || exit
for f in *.mp4; do
ratio=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=display_aspect_ratio -of csv=p=0 "$f")
if [ "$ratio" = 2:1 ]
then
  echo "$f"
fi
done
```

The above script will simply print the names of the files to be deleted. If these match properly you can change `echo "$f"` to `rm -f "$f"`.

Or a recursive version using `find`:

```
cd "/torrents/complete"
find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -exec bash -c 'ratio=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=display_aspect_ratio -of csv=p=0 "$1"); if [[ "$ratio" == 2:1 ]]; then echo "$1"; fi' _ {} \;
```

The above command will simply print the names of the files to be deleted. If these match properly you can change `echo "$1"` to `rm -f "$1"`.

Comment: thanks it works. Any idea how to filter out this false positive? See edit

Comment: @Ivanov There is nothing listed in your mediainfo output that can be used to differentiate it from a 3D video. Actually mediainfo output is less helpful than including the full output from `ffmpeg -i falsepositive.mp4 -i exampleof3dvideo.mp4`. There may be metadata that could be of use that is not present in the mediainfo output.

Comment: "Actually mediainfo output is less helpful than including the full output from ffmpeg" it depends a lot on if the metadata format (if present) is supported by any of the tools, FFmpeg would be less helpful if it does not support the metadata format and MediaInfo does. In short, your sentence is not always true. (disclaimer: MediaInfo developer speaking)

Comment: @JérômeMartinez I'm not disparaging  mediainfo, but generally when answering ffmpeg questions the ffmpeg output is usually more helpful for me.